# Kubernetes - How to list all pods running in a particular instance group?

Tags: kubectl, kops, kubernetes

How can I list, using command line, all the pods running in the nodes of a particular instance group?

For example, if I have instancegroup "Foo", which has let's say three nodes, N1, N2, and N3, that in turn have pods A and B running on N1, pods C, D and E running on N2, and pod F running on N3.... how can I, using kops/kubectl, make query with input "Foo" and output "A, B, C, D, E, F"?

I know that you can query a particular node and list all the pods in it, but I want to query an instancegroup, with many nodes, and get all the pods across all the nodes, with no namespace constraint.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be to assign labels to the nodes in your InstanceGroup, perhaps with the name of the instance group (for simplicity) and then use a combination of kubectl commands to query.

So in your InstanceGroup spec set `nodeLabels` to be `ig: Foo` (see https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/master/docs/instance_groups.md#adding-taints-or-labels-to-an-instance-group) for details and then run:

`kubectl get pods -o wide --all-namespaces | grep -F -f <(kubectl get nodes -l ig=Foo --no-headers | awk '{print $1}')`

Comment: hmm your answer does not quite work yet, but it helped me figure it out. I had to make this changes for it to work:
- remove the "v" from grep  -v, since "-v" is for invert matches
- add --all-namespaces to kubectl get pods so it will search in all namespaces, as stated in my question
- add -o wide to kubect get pods so it will list the node in the output, otherwise there is nothing to grep.

if you edit your answer I'll marked as accepted. thanks!

Comment: @jotadepicas thanks for your points. my test cluster only had one node so had false positives. Your requirement of "no namespace constraint" cause me a bit of confusion hence the omission but yeah. Go team